# When i do a vagrant provisioning, can i ignore some provision codes from Vagrantfile on vagrant reload?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

In my Vagrantfile, I have two shell provisions: one is for installing system dependencies for my project, and another is for starting up nginx server.

So what I wanted to have is when I `vagrant reload --provision`, can I ignore the provision for installing the system dependencies, and just start up the nginx server instead?

Sample code:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    ...

    # Ignore this line on VM reload
    config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'provision/install.sh'

    # Execute this one only on VM reload
    config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'provision/start_nginx.sh'

    ...

end
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution, but a little bit hack method is

You can pass environment variables while running vagrant reload command like this

```
RELOAD=true vagrant reload --provision
```

then in `VagrantFile`

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    ...

    # Ignore this line on VM reload
    if (ENV['RELOAD'] != true)
        config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'provision/install.sh'
    end

    # Execute this one only on VM reload
    config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'provision/start_nginx.sh'

    ...

end
```