# Conditionally call different provision in Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have the following provisions setup in my Vagrant file.

```
 config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/bootstrap.sh"
 config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/step-1.sh"
 config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/step-2.sh"
 config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/dev-setup.sh"
```

`provision/bootstrap.sh` needs to be run always, however i need to conditionally run the remaining provisions. For Eg. if `dev` mode, run the `provision/dev-setup.sh`

Is there some inbuilt Vagrant config setting to achieve this?  ( like passing command line args to `vagrant provision`) ?

I would not like to rely on ENV variables like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221619/when-i-do-a-vagrant-provisioning-can-i-ignore-some-provision-codes-from-vagrant) if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think environment variables are the most common way to handle this, and there isn't a way to pass anything through the `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision` command. Here are a couple of alternative ideas you could explore:

1. Have something else that is different on the Dev versus Prod environment. The Vagrantfile is just a Ruby script, so anything that can be detected can be used to control the provisioning script sequence. For example, presence/absence of a file, local network, hostname, etc.
2. Define separate Vagrant nodes which are actually the same, but differ based on provisioning. For example with a file like the following, you could do `vagrant up prod` or `vagrant up dev`, depending on your environment:

   ```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/bootstrap.sh"
     config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/step-1.sh"
     config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/step-2.sh"

     config.vm.define "prod" do |prod|
       ...
     end

     config.vm.define "dev" do |dev|
       ...
       config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/dev-setup.sh"

     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new variable in your inventory to hold the environment, for example `env: dev` in the dev inventory and `env: production` in the prod inventory and then use that to conditionally include your individual task files, like this:

```
# provision.yml (your main playbook)

- include: provision/bootstrap.sh
- include: provision/step-1.sh
- include: provision/step-2.sh
- include: provision/dev-setup.sh
  when: env == 'dev'
```

Then in Vagrant you can specify the inventory to use, for example:

```
config.vm.provision "provision", type: "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = 'provision.yml'
    ansible.inventory_path = 'inventory/dev'
end
```

More info:

- [Conditional includes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#id9)
- [Inventories](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html)